# concatenate a string to the end of every output line in bash/csh

Tags: bash, string-concatenation

In bash command line, if I run "find . -name 'abc*' ", it prints out a list of filenames like

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

How can I pipe it with echo or other command, so that i get this output:

```
abc1   ok
abc2   ok
abc3   ok
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
find . -name 'abc*' | sed 's/$/\tok/' | column -t
```

`sed` appends the string `<Tab>ok` to each line, and `column` formats the output nicely (you can just skip this, if you don't need it).

Answer (score 10):

I tend to write:

```
whatever | while read line; do echo $line ok; done
```

That might be overkill for something this simple, but it becomes the simplest thing to do if you want to do more complicated things with the line. And it doesn't involve remembering how to make sed work!

Answer (score 6):

With GNU find,

```
find . -name "abc*" -printf "%f ok\n"
```

Comment: Simple and doesn't need another tool. +1

Answer (score 5):

Simply:

```
$ find . -name 'abc*' | xargs -I {} echo {} OK
```

Comment: Not really different from my answer, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Pipe it through sed, is one way:

```
 | sed -e 's/\(^.*\)/\1   ok/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xargs`:

```
find -iname "abc" | xargs -IREPL echo REPL ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `paste` standard command. Or for each element of what `find` shall get you manually echo the filename and the result of a function on that filename.

Can you please tell what you finally want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

```
find . -name "abc*" -exec echo "{} - ok" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'abc*' -exec echo {}' OK' \; | column -t
```